# Many components with the same reducer but different initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I tested Redux with creating a little RPG game.

I have a component called Monster who move on the map. The position, the direction and the spriteLocation are controlled by the store. The monster Reducer look like this:

```
const intialState = {
   position: [0,360],
   spriteLocation: '0px 80px',
   direction: 'EAST',
   walkIndex : 0
}

const monsterReducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
       case 'MOVE_MONSTER':
           return {
               ...action.payload
           }
       default:
           return state
   }
}

export default monsterReducer
```

The moves are dispatched like that:

```
import store from '../../config/store'
import {SPRITE_SIZE, MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT} from '../../config/constants'

export default function handleMovement(monster){

    //APPEL AU DEPLACEMENT TOUTES LES X secondes
    // setInterval(handleMove(store.getState().monster.direction), 500);
    setInterval(() => {
        handleMove(store.getState().monster.direction)
      }, 300);

    function handleMove(direction){
        switch(direction){
            case 'WEST':
                return attemptMove('WEST')
            case 'EAST':
                return attemptMove('EAST')
            case 'NORTH':
                return attemptMove('NORTH')
            case 'SOUTH':
                return attemptMove('SOUTH')
            default:
        }
    }

    function attemptMove(direction){
        const oldPos = store.getState().monster.position
        const newPos = getNewPosition(oldPos,direction)
        if(observeBoundaries(newPos) && observeImpassable(newPos)){
            dispatchMove(direction, newPos)
        }else{
            switch(direction){
                case 'WEST':
                    return attemptMove('EAST')
                case 'EAST':
                    return attemptMove('WEST')
                case 'NORTH':
                    return attemptMove('SOUTH')
                case 'SOUTH':
                    return attemptMove('NORTH')
                default:
            }
        }
    }

    //UPDATE DE LA POSITION
    function getNewPosition(oldPos, direction){
        switch(direction){
            case 'WEST':
                return [oldPos[0]-SPRITE_SIZE, oldPos[1]]
            case 'EAST':
                return [oldPos[0]+SPRITE_SIZE, oldPos[1]]
            case 'NORTH':
                return [oldPos[0], oldPos[1]-SPRITE_SIZE]
            case 'SOUTH':
                return [oldPos[0], oldPos[1]+SPRITE_SIZE]
            default:
        }        
    }

    function observeBoundaries(newPos){
        //SI ON EST DANS LA MAP ON RETOURNE TRUE SINON FALSE
        return (newPos[0] >= 0 && newPos[0] <= MAP_WIDTH-SPRITE_SIZE) &&
                (newPos[1] >= 0 && newPos[1] <= MAP_HEIGHT-SPRITE_SIZE)
    }

    function observeImpassable(newPos){
        //TEST DES OBSTACLES
        const tiles = store.getState().map.tiles
        const y = newPos[1] / SPRITE_SIZE
        const x = newPos[0] / SPRITE_SIZE
        const nextTile = tiles[y][x]
        return  nextTile < 5
    }

    function getWalkIndex(){
        const walkIndex = store.getState().monster.walkIndex
        return walkIndex >= 4 ? 0 : walkIndex+1
    }

    function getSpriteLocation(direction, walkIndex){
        switch (direction){
            case 'EAST' :
                return `${SPRITE_SIZE*walkIndex}px ${SPRITE_SIZE*2}px`
            case 'SOUTH' :
                return `${SPRITE_SIZE*walkIndex}px ${SPRITE_SIZE*0}px`
            case 'WEST' :
                return `${SPRITE_SIZE*walkIndex}px ${SPRITE_SIZE*3}px`
            case 'NORTH' :
                return `${SPRITE_SIZE*walkIndex}px ${SPRITE_SIZE*1}px`
            default:

        }
    }

    //DISPATCH DE LA NOUVELLE POSITION ET DIRECTION POUR ANIMATION DU PERSO AU STORE
    function dispatchMove(direction, newPos){
        const walkIndex = getWalkIndex()
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'MOVE_MONSTER',
            payload: {
                position: newPos,
                direction,
                walkIndex,
                spriteLocation : getSpriteLocation(direction, walkIndex)
            }
        })
    }

    return  monster
}
```

I would like to create another Monster component but with different initial state but who works with the same reducer.

Maybe it's not the good solution to use reducer for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux is used to share state within the component not to hold a single component state. So in this case monster component can have own state or if still, you want reducer there you have to change the structure of reducer.

```
const intialState = {
   monsters: {
   }
}

const monsterReducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
       case 'MOVE_MONSTER':
           return {
               ...action.payload
           }
       default:
           return state
   }
}

export default monsterReducer
```

So whenever a monster is registered you can initilize monster in same reducer.
i.e.

`registerMonster(id)` - when new monster action

reducer

```
case "REGISETER_MONSTER":
    return {
       ...state,
       [action.payload.id]: {
           position: [0,360],
           spriteLocation: '0px 80px',
           direction: 'EAST',
           walkIndex : 0
       }
    }
```

the id should be unique for each monster and then updation logic will also change there you have to pass the id of monster and update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I understand the logic but I can't understand where I can set the initial state of each Monster when I register them.

Comment: Where you planning to create monster dynamically on the go or like there will be N no of monsters always.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think my React level is too low to directly understand so I'll try things base on your help. Thanks again !

Comment: It's ok I juste replace my functional component Monster by a Class Component and not use Redux..
Thanks for your help